# What are the fields/keywords for email?

Tags: android

I am creating an app to generate QR Code for email. For that i need to know the keywords like for address it is "mailto:" . I want to know keywords for **cc, bcc, subject and message**

```
contents = "mailto:";

            String to = bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL);
            String cc = bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_CC);
            String bcc = bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_BCC);
            String subject = bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT);
            String mailText = bundle.getString(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);

            if (!to.isEmpty() && !subject.isEmpty() && !mailText.isEmpty()) {

                contents = contents + to + "\n";

                if (!cc.isEmpty() && !bcc.isEmpty()) {
                    contents = "cc:" + cc + "\n";
                    contents = "bcc:" + bcc + "\n";
                }
                contents = "subject:" + subject + "\n";
                contents = "message:" + mailText;
            }
```

I want to keywords for creating my contents string

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sending_email.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use this method:

```
public static Intent email(Context context, String[] to, String [] cc, String [] bcc, String subject, String body, Uri attachment) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto:"));
    if (to != null)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, to);
    if (cc != null)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_CC, cc);
    if (bcc != null)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_BCC, bcc);
    if (body != null)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body);
    if (subject != null)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
    if (attachment != null)
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    return intent;
}
```

Comment: Yeah thats right. But this is not my problem. I have edited the question. Kindly check it

Comment: @user3917800 so i don't think there is a way to do it inside the "data" field. why won't you do it this way?

Comment: Actually i am generating QR Code for email. That's why i need this

Comment: I seed. Unfortunately, if you want to work with all *email* apps, you will have to use an official API. Your technique will maybe work on some email clients, but not on all.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no information about the email format. If i know the format, my problem will be solved in seconds

Comment: @user3917800 there is no info because each app can implement their own format. Following the official format is also the best way to have the best compatibility possible

Comment: @user3917800 The official format is the one I put in my answer

Answer (score 0):

Atlast I found the solution. The correct format to generate QR Code for email is,

To write an email message as a QR Code, you need to write it in the following format:

MATMSG:TO: john@example.com;

SUB: My comments on your story;

BODY: I just finished reading your story on QR codes. Thanks ;;

**notice the semicolons**